How can I type  on Windows?
I tried:

hold down Alt, press +, press the Unicode hex value 1F9DE, release Alt. This does not work because when I press the F key, it triggers the File menu (Alt+F hotkey) of the browser. In Notepad or WordPad, it shows 吏.

Hold down Alt, press the Unicode decimal 129502 on the numeric keypad, release Alt, but it shows ▐.

Hold down Alt, press 0129502 on the numeric keypad, release Alt, but it shows Þ


How can I type the emoji  correctly? I know I can use Win + . to pop up the emoji window to get the emoji, but I'm curious why the Alt + code method does not work.

Did you do this registry modification?

@harrymc Yes, I've done that.

The "Alt+" method has serious drawbacks and only seems to work
(when it works) for Unicode characters that are up to four characters in length, while yours has five characters.
So here are some alternate methods:

The "Alt digits" method seems to work better. The hex value for the
Genie character
is 1f9de, and its decimal code is 129502.
Typing "Alt-down 129502 Alt-up" will enter this character
(using only numeric keypad digits).
Note that the current font must contain the character in order to
display it. You may use the Windows calculator in Programmer mode
to convert hex to decimal.

In Word, you may enter the Genie character by typing "1f9de Alt-X".
This works quite well as long as the preceding character cannot be
understood as a hexadecimal digit.

There exist various utilities for Unicode input. The Windows
Emoji keyboard can also be used here (with some difficulty).



I type "Alt-down 129502 Alt-up" in notepad++, and it shows▐. I copy the Genie emoji from here to notepad++, it can shows normally(just becomes black and white).

I type "Alt-down 129502 Alt-up" here in the comment, and it also shows ▐

Yes, it doesn't work in all programs. It works for me in notepad, wordpad and Word. It doesn't work as you found in notepad++, Chrome,  Edge, Firefox. Unicode implementation in Windows has since always been patchy. Maybe something to do with the input mode of the program.

I just tried wordpad, the alt-code method works. But it does not work in my notepad.

That's strange, but entering Unicode in Windows was always very chancy. There are utilities that do it correctly, but the simplest sure method is the copy-paste. Unfortunately.

Apparently, this is because only some of the digits are registered, so e. g., Alt+128522 becomes Alt+522 (I think the wrapping uses some hexadecimal stuff, because it's not simply removing the first three digits, as you can test with Alt+129502).
Previously, apparently you could use registry hack with EnableHexNumpad for longer alt codes, but that doesn't seem to work on Windows 11 anymore.
